# cart is not working with more than 3 variations Woocommeerce.?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the website from the client for his food services. well, I have used woo-commerce it works fine with no variations and with at least 3 variations but on 3 variations take 1 min to add items on the cart. but when I use 4 variations it keeps load too long and in the end after 10 to 15 minutes give error wp-DB time execute more than 240s. I even increased the time from phpmyadmin but nothing is resolved. I am quite sure something is wrong with woo-commerce but no idea what and how will it be resolved. Thanks

Comment: Update to the latest version of WooCommerce if you haven't already and see if the issue persists.

Comment: i have latest version of woocommerce already

Comment: Disable all other plugins except WooCommerce and see if the issue remains.